DataSnap - Object as server method parameter
Is it currently (Delphi 12) possible to write in server method parameters some class and receive it from simple JSON?
Now I have:
type
    TTestParam = class
        fVal1: Integer;
    end;

    {$METHODINFO ON}
    TTest = class(TDSServerModule)
    strict private
    public
        function updateTest(param: TJsonObject): TTestParam;
    end;
    {$METHODINFO OFF}

implementation

function TTest.updateTest(param: TJsonObject): TTestParam;
var
    lParam: TTestParam;
begin
    lParam := TTestParam.Create;
    try
        TJson.JsonToObject(lParam, param);

        Result := TTestParam.Create;
        Result.fVal1 := lParam.fVal1 * 2;
    finally
        lParam.Free;
    end;
end;

My expectation:
function TTest.updateTest(param: TTestParam
): TTestParam;
begin
        Result := TTestParam.Create;
        Result.fVal1 := Param.fVal1 * 2;
end;

BTW - for output I a little wrapper on WebDispacher event:
var
  Aux: TJSONValue;
begin
  //remove [] element
    Aux := ResultVal;
    ResultVal := TJSONArray(Aux).Items[0];
    ResultVal.Owned := False;
    //TJSONArray(Aux).Remove(0);
    Aux.Free;

    Aux := ResultVal;
    ResultVal := TJSONObject(Aux).GetValue('fields');
    ResultVal.Owned := False;
    Aux.Free;

    Handled := true;
end;

Can I do maybe some reverted for input?

The allowed parameter and function result types are documented: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Exposing_DataSnap_Server_Methods

I looking for some bypass this restrictions and use some native class. It's horrible, that Embarcadero boasts support REST servers, but all is projected for works only, if you use only their products for make server and client side.

You can convert any plain data object into a TJSONObject with TJson.ObjectToJSONObject: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/REST.Json.TJson.ObjectToJsonObject

I know, but I need object in parameter to use RTTI for build documentation - I can't convert in function JSON to object. Who invented such a useless thing as datasnap? :(

IMHO your last comment is unfair at least. There are plenty of Datasnap applications out there without their developers making such complaints. You seem to be too fixated on your personal problem. If Datasnap doesn't fit your needs you are free to use something else. That doesn't make Datasnap useless at all.

@Uwe Raabe - You have right. DataSnap is not for me :) I writing my own REST server now :)
